# Pushed to wrong postgresql database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, database-connection

I used an URI in `.env` to connect my code to the database of my app, but it connected to the `postgres` database instead of the database `"workout-app"` and I don't know how to fix that. My application created tables in the wrong database.

This is my `.env` file:

```
NODE_ENV = development
DATABASE_URL = postgresql://postgres:2341/@localhost:5432/workout-app?schema=public
ACCESS_TOKEN = SDFvmtee3t
```

I tried to rename database `postgres`, but it is imposible. I checked if the link is correct 1000 times and I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: I'm betting the `/` in `2341/` is causing the issue. Assuming you are using `node-postgres(pg)` the connection string needs to match the examples here  [pg-connection string](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/tree/master/packages/pg-connection-string).

Answer (score 0):

The connection URI would be the one described in the [node-postgres documentation](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/tree/master/packages/pg-connection-string#connection-strings).

In that case, the connection URI is wrong.

First, the scheme should be `postgres:`, not `postgresql:`.

Second, it looks like you are trying to connect as user `postgres` with password `2341/`, but you didn't URI-encode the password properly. It would have to be `2341%2F`.

Finally, the parameter `schema` does not exist.

**Never, under no circumstance, run your application with a superuser.**

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to the issue! No, I use node js as my programming language. This link format works correctly in videos in the courses where I study. Almost everything in the code is executed correctly, except for the name of the database where the tables are loaded. I'll also try to read the documentation you posted a link to and fix the problem.

Comment: Given that  the OP is using Node I'm guessing the driver is actually [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/) which can use [pg-connection string](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/tree/master/packages/pg-connection-string).

Answer (score 0):

I'm just a beginner and I don't know how this happened, but the problem was solved when I tried to push the tables with the server turned off. If the server was turned on, then prisma asked to unlink a certain file from node models. Sorry for wasting your time.